# How to use key word lambda as a parameter in XGBoost in Python?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, xgboost

I try to train XGBoost machine learning model in Python and I am wondering how to use parameter "lambda" in this model, because as you are awar "lambda" is a key word for Python.

I have code like:

```
XGB_4 = xgb.sklearn.XGBClassifier(n_estimators = 500,
                                  lambda = 15)
```

and error:

```
    lambda = 15,
           ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I use "lambda" as a parameter in Python ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [docs](https://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/python/python_api.html#xgboost.XGBClassifier), the Python version of the parameter name is `reg_lambda`, so instead of `lambda=15`, use `reg_lambda=15`.

Comment: alfo for classification problem ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking.  The class is `XGBClassifier`, and the parameter `reg_lambda` is described as "L2 regularization term on weights (xgb’s lambda)."  Is that not what you want?